# Getting "invalid authorization specification" when creating linked server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have two databases. Database A is on DBServer\Instance1 and Database B is on DBServer\Instance2. I need to create a view inside Database B that looks into a table in Database A. I was told I need to add DBServer\Instance1 as a linked server to DBServer\Instance2 first. That's what I'm trying to do.

Just for testing, I created a user account named `linked_server_acct` and gave it all the roles on both servers (Under Security > Logins). I can log in to each instance using SQL Management Studio, so I know for a fact that the login works, but I'm not able to use it for some reason when creating the linked servers. It fails with "invalid authentication specification - 7399'.

I can't think of a reason why an account that is basically a super admin of a server can't authenticate to it. Any help would be appreciated.

DBServer\Instance1 linked server script:

```
/****** Object:  LinkedServer [DBSERVER\INSTANCE1]    Script Date: 

06/17/2015 16:17:39 ******/
EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedserver @server = N'DBSERVER\INSTANCE1', @srvproduct=N'SQL Server'
 /* For security reasons the linked server remote logins password is changed with ######## */
EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedsrvlogin @rmtsrvname=N'DBSERVER\INSTANCE1',@useself=N'False',@locallogin=NULL,@rmtuser=NULL,@rmtpassword=NULL
EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedsrvlogin @rmtsrvname=N'DBSERVER\INSTANCE1',@useself=N'True',@locallogin=N'linked_server_acct',@rmtuser=NULL,@rmtpassword=NULL

GO

EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'DBSERVER\INSTANCE1', @optname=N'collation compatible', @optvalue=N'false'
GO

EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'DBSERVER\INSTANCE1', @optname=N'data access', @optvalue=N'true'
GO

EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'DBSERVER\INSTANCE1', @optname=N'dist', @optvalue=N'false'
GO

EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'DBSERVER\INSTANCE1', @optname=N'pub', @optvalue=N'false'
GO

EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'DBSERVER\INSTANCE1', @optname=N'rpc', @optvalue=N'false'
GO

EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'DBSERVER\INSTANCE1', @optname=N'rpc out', @optvalue=N'false'
GO

EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'DBSERVER\INSTANCE1', @optname=N'sub', @optvalue=N'false'
GO

EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'DBSERVER\INSTANCE1', @optname=N'connect timeout', @optvalue=N'0'
GO

EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'DBSERVER\INSTANCE1', @optname=N'collation name', @optvalue=null
GO

EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'DBSERVER\INSTANCE1', @optname=N'lazy schema validation', @optvalue=N'false'
GO

EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'DBSERVER\INSTANCE1', @optname=N'query timeout', @optvalue=N'0'
GO

EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'DBSERVER\INSTANCE1', @optname=N'use remote collation', @optvalue=N'true'
GO

EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'DBSERVER\INSTANCE1', @optname=N'remote proc transaction promotion', @optvalue=N'true'
GO
```

Comment: Please script out the linked server definitions and edit your question to include the scripts in a code block.

Comment: Sorry, can you clarify? I'm not using any scripts. I'm using the SQL Management Studio GUI.

Comment: Are both servers in same domain?

Comment: Yes. Same machine, different SQL instances.

Comment: Yes, that is what I figured.  But you can select the linked servers and generate a script that will let others see exactly how the linked server and security are set up.  Choose Server Objects / Linked Servers / ServerName, then right click and choose 'Script Linked Server ...'

Comment: Gotcha. See my edit. Let me know if that's what you need.

Comment: Any thoughts on this? Did I provide the correct script?

Comment: It does not look like there is a problem with the linked server definition. So it seems that your authentication is the problem. Go to the linked server properties and try
using the "login's current security context" or "Be made using this security context" to test your connection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured out the problem. Even though the user I was adding to the Linked Server security section had permissions into the target database, the user I was logged into the SQL Server instance at the moment didn't. Since the error message is incredibly unhelpful (it doesn't say which user failed to log in), I discovered this entirely by accident.